# date-fns: How to format dates for multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-fns, javascript-date

I'm using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) in my React web app, and support multiple languages (English, French, and Spanish). I want to display the date in a way that makes sense to users of any of these three languages, and right now I do it like this:

```
import en from 'date-fns/locale/en';
import fr from 'date-fns/locale/fr';
import es from 'date-fns/locale/es';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
...
const locale = fr; // or en, or es
format(new Date(), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a', { locale })
```

For English this gives `April 14, 2023 1:40 PM`

For French this gives `avril 14, 2023 1:40 PM`

For Spanish this gives `abril 14, 2023 1:40 PM`

**The Problem:** Even though this is translating the individual terms, it's still formatting them all the same way. I don't know if `avril 14, 2023 1:40 PM` is the correct order to put the terms in in French.

**What I Want To Know:** Is there a way to just print the date in a way that makes sense for the chosen language, rather than hard-coding a format?

Comment: If you specify the format, then what else is date-fns to do but respect the format? `new Date().toLocaleString('es',{year:'numeric', month:'long', day:'numeric', hour:'numeric', minute:'numeric'})` returns something like "15 de abril de 2023, 21:23". Note that "locale" is a misnomer for language and there are a number of regional variants: AR, CL, CO, ES, MX, US.

Comment: Just for info
"I don't know if avril 14, 2023 1:40 PM is the correct order to put the terms in in French." 
--> no the correct order is :  14 avril 2023 13:40